# Confluentinc connector. Multiple connectors in one elasticsearch index. Publish in specific document type

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a problem with Confluentinc connector.

When you creating the connector you need to specify topic (elasticsearch index) and type (document type in ES).

```
{
  "name": "test-connector",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "test",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "schema.ignore": "false",
    "connection.url": "http://elastic:9200",
    "type.name": "type1",
    "name": "elasticsearch-sink"
  }
}
```

I want to publish in the same index (kafka topic) but to different types, is it possible?

I've tried to create multiple connectors, but the problem, that it every connector consume the message, because it's a same topic.

I've tried to create connector on the fly with specific type, publish there and then remove connector. But sometimes it removing too early and not all messages are consumed (didn't appear in elastic). Also when i'm removing connector and creating another one with other document type, this new connector consumes some of old messages.

Does anyone have an idea how to manage this?

Comment: So you want the same messages to go to the same index but against different types? Or different messages from the same topic to go to different types?

Comment: @RobinMoffatt hi, i want different messages from same topic to go to different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found a solution, unfortunately it is deprecated. If you know something better, please let me know.

From official docs:

```
topic.index.map
This option is now deprecated. A future version may remove it completely. Please use single message transforms, such as RegexRouter, to map topic names to index names.

A map from Kafka topic name to the destination Elasticsearch index, represented as a list of topic:index pairs.

Type: list
Default: ""
Importance: low
```

so i've created connector like that:

```
{
  "name": "test-connector-old",
  "config": {
  .....
    "topics": "old",
    "topic.index.map": "old:test",
....
  }
}
```

now i can push to topic "old" and it will index elasticsearch "test" index

then i've created more connectors, and using "topic.index.map": "**TOPIC_NAME**:test", i could index different types on the same index

in future versions it  will be topic => index. Confluent team, please don't remove topic.index.map, or find better solution for this case
Thank you!

Comment: `RegexRouter` **is** the replacement, as mentioned in the docs

Answer (score 0):

Each connector can route messages to one type. You can use Single Message Transform to route messages to different indices, but this is not what you want.

What I would recommend is use stream processing to split the messages into different topics. Each topic is then streamed by a different connector to the same index but different type as required.

To do the stream processing you could use something like Kafka Streams, Spark Streaming, etc etc. There's also [KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/product/ksql/), which would let you do something like this:

```
CREATE STREAM FOO_TYPE_A AS SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE TYPE='A';
CREATE STREAM FOO_TYPE_B AS SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE TYPE='B';
CREATE STREAM FOO_TYPE_C AS SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE TYPE='C';
```

You then have three topics (`FOO_TYPE_A`, `FOO_TYPE_B`, `FOO_TYPE_C`) that you create three connectors for, streaming to index `FOO` but with different types.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, the company behind the open-source KSQL project.*

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Still i don't really get how can i "create three connectors for, streaming to index FOO but with different types", because when i'm creating connector i'm specifying also topic (index in elastic). Or what should i write then in "topics" in connector? because if i will specify something else it would be a different index then.

Comment: or can you give an example of connector (using docker), which listen topic "FOO_TYPE_A" but pushing in index "FOO"? Because i was searching that in your docs, but didn't find anything like that